# merge array into content

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create a function that will merge an array into a template that I have created please see below :

My array:

```
  $view_array = array();
  $view_array['start.form'] = '<form method="POST" >';
  $view_array['end.form'] = '</form>';
  $view_array['name.input'] = '<label>Name : </label><input type="text" name="frm_name" />';
  $view_array['name.input'] = '<label>E-mail: </label><input type="text" name="frm_email" />';
  $view_array['submit.form'] = '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />';
```

My template:

```
$content = "
    ~error.messages~

    ~start.form~

    ~name.input~

    ~email.input~

    ~submit.from~

    ~end.form~";
```

Comment: Why not use an existing templating engine? Anyway, `preg_replace_callback` is your friend if you want to write it for yourself.

Comment: I'm integrating my module into wordpress so i just need a simple function.

Comment: Doesn't wordpress already provide some templating functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($view_array AS $key=>$value)
{
$content = str_replace('~'.$key.'~',$value,$content);
}

echo $content;
```

Comment: What do you mean by addition ~? only one at the end of string? or end of line?